# How to implement Signed Exchanges (SXGs) in WordPress website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

We have a WordPress website we trying to improve core web vitals.

When implementing SXGs can improve Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) for some sites.

That's why we planned for implementing Signed Exchanges (SXGs) in WordPress websites

So please help me how to implement Signed Exchanges (SXGs) in WordPress websites.

Comment: Are you just trying to score higher in some tool, such as Lighthouse, or do you have additional reasons why you want to implement this? If the former, there are literally dozens of things you should do first. SXG only increases performance if a cache is used in front of your site. So search users from Google might see a boost, but general traffic won’t benefit (at this point in time, at least).

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention
I like to use sxg for these reasons

Comment: A signed exchange (SXG) is a delivery mechanism that makes it possible to authenticate the origin of a resource independently of how it was delivered. This decoupling advances a variety of use cases such as privacy-preserving prefetching, offline internet experiences, and serving from third-party caches. Additionally, implementing SXGs can improve Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) for some sites.

Comment: Yes, I know what an SXG, and generally speaking, just copy and pasting something from somewhere on the internet without attribution is frowned upon. First, get a certificate from DigiCert, they are the only CA that supports this, and the only CA that has shown interest in this since inception. Second, follow [Google’s instructions](https://web.dev/how-to-set-up-signed-http-exchanges/). If you were hoping for a simple WordPress plugin route, I doubt one will exist, at least in the near future.

Comment: Do you think it is useful to use it or not?
And how much can it help?
Thank you for your help

Comment: I think SXG is great in theory, but like many plans where HTML gets cached on a CDN, you should be prepared for a giant headache when you try to invalidate that cache. If you really want to implement this, I would talk to your site developer(s) and server administrator(s) because they will need to fully understand the ramifications of this. Your webserver is suddenly going to start behaving in a non-traditional way, people will be shift-refreshing and things just won't work as expected, unless everyone is on board.